# how to stop cloud sql instance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql

I am using this gcloud command to stop  my sql instance following [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance)

```
   gcloud sql instances patch my-sql-instance --activation-policy NEVER
```

how can I achieve the same in nodejs code?

is there a google library for the sql api in npm?

Answer (score 1):

using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) 
see also the [api reference](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/reference/rest/v1beta4/instances/patch)

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
const sqladmin = google.sqladmin('v1beta4');

auth.getApplicationDefault((_err, authRes) => {
    var req = {
        auth: authRes.credential,
        project: "my-project-id",
        instance: "my-instance",
        requestBody: {
            "settings": {
                "activationPolicy": "NEVER"
            }
        }
    };
    sqladmin.instances.patch(req, (err, res) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        if (res) console.info(res);
    })
});
```